# Connecting GWT widget and JIRA

Tags: gwt, jira

I have a GWT screen in which i have a file upload bar,whenever i attach something and click send,the request should go on server side which in turn logs an JIRA request with attachment as the same which was attached to my GWT widget.

Not able to code it.

I've made the particular widget. Server side processing which includes raising JIRA request is remaining.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to upload an attachment to a JIRA issue I would recommend you to use the JIRA built-in REST API.

See information on the operation of attachment POST here: https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/jira/4.4.1.html#id149632

And general information on REST implementation here: 
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs

So basically the process would be as follows: You initiate upload from client side to your server, your server validates the file and then uploads file to JIRA via the REST API.

Comment: thanks...and how to upload that file..using stream or something...i'm not able to get it...do u have any idea and some sample code ?

Comment: you mean upload file from GWT to server?

Comment: on gwt side you can use the FileUpload widget: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html And on server side I can recommend to use Spring MVC framework, here an example how to process the upload: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/

Comment: do u have any example on how to use the rest API in my java code...
like i have to set a JSON object which will help me calling the rest api's link(for eg :- /rest/api/2/issue) and then i've to create a JIRA issue with this link , as i'm new to JIRA n JSON, how to write the piece of code...m not getting it...how to request and process response....could you please help me ..THANKS